# The id R.id.gdsph_btn has already been looked up in this method; possible cut and paste error?

Tags: java, android, paste, cut

I am Newbie In programming and I am making an app in which if you click a button an audio will play. But I am Getting Above error. Here is my full code. Please Help. Please Help me solve this error"The id R.id.gdsph_btn has already been looked up in this method;  possible cut and paste error?"

```
package com.agrimplayz.radhasoamipaath;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button rrjk_btn, gdsph_btn, aspamm, stop_btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rrjk_btn = findViewById(R.id.rrjk_btn);
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.radhasoami_rakshak_jeev_ke);

    rrjk_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        int counter = 0;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           if(counter == 2)
               mediaPlayer.pause();
           mediaPlayer.start();


            gdsph_btn = findViewById(R.id.gdsph_btn);
            final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, 
R.raw.guru_dhara_sheesh_par_haath);

                gdsph_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });


            aspamm = findViewById(R.id.gdsph_btn);
            final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, 
R.raw.ae_satguru_pita_aur_malik_mere);

            aspamm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();

                }
            });
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 lines:

```
            aspamm = findViewById(R.id.gdsph_btn);
```

and

```
            gdsph_btn = findViewById(R.id.gdsph_btn);
```

Both variables refer to the same button and that's the error you are getting. Either refer aspamm / gdsph to a different button or don't use 2 variables for same button.

Also, this is not an error, it's a warning, to tell you that you either override the needed functionality for your button or your code can be more efficient as it's useless to search by ID an object you searched for 2 lines ago